# How to get current prices of buying or selling using different api..?

Tags: php, bitcoin

Any one have idea about the list of bitcoin providers or list of api which will give me current bitcoin prices of buying or selling also they provided facility to buy or sell bitcoin using their api.

For example : see below link which will give me current bitcoin prices of buy/sell

```
Buy : https://www.igot.com/api/v1/stats/buy
sell : https://www.igot.com/api/v1/stats/sell
```

But they only provide the current prices but I also want to buy/sell from the api.

Please let me know if any one having idea ..?